Vs code android emulator not working with flutter
Guys I am trying to learn app development through flutter. Below is the link to image of my screen with the flutter code and the android emulator. No matter how many times I try to run the code the emulator screen keeps showing me this white screen with flutter logo on it.
Whereas it should be all red color. I have tried restarting the vs code, also cleared the cache files and everything my noob mind can think off. But no success. Pls help!!
My screen https://ibb.co/pnWHYtN

wrap your MaterialApp with runApp();
eg. runApp(MaterialApp()); and watch a tutorial. get started with flutter

The Flutter logo is a loading screen. Sometimes, it takes a long time to load the app. I see no issues in your code, so maybe just wait a little longer.

U have 1 error in widget_test.dart file, fix this error and try again or delete this file
